# Here is what I facing this issue, Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, null given

Tags: mysql, laravel

This is the error I'm getting:

```
    $order_items = DB::select("SELECT i.`id`,i.`chef_id`,i.`selected_date_type`,i.`delivery_date`, REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(g.items), ' ', ' '), ' ', ', ') AS collection_items ,
                    CONCAT(chef_address.latitude,", ",chef_address.longitude) AS source_address,CONCAT(customer_address.latitude,", ",customer_address.longitude) AS destination_address 
                        FROM order_item i INNER JOIN ( SELECT `delivery_date`,`selected_date_type`,`chef_id`,`order_id`, GROUP_CONCAT(`id` SEPARATOR ' ') AS items 
                            FROM order_item GROUP BY `delivery_date`, `selected_date_type`, `chef_id`,`order_id` ) g ON g.`delivery_date` = i.`delivery_date` AND g.`selected_date_type` = i.`selected_date_type` AND g.`chef_id` = i.`chef_id` AND g.`order_id`= i.`order_id`
                                inner join `orders` on `orders`.`id` = i.`order_id` inner join `user_address` as `customer_address` on `customer_address`.`id` = `orders`.`address_id` 
                                    inner join `user_address` as `chef_address` on `chef_address`.`user_id` = i.`chef_id` WHERE i.`order_id` = ( ? )",[$orderCart->id]);
```

This query is run fine in my DB but in laravel not working !

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what version of Laravel are you using? and you are sure it is this query throwing that error?

Comment: I am using laravel 8 , yes this query throwing error

Comment: TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, string given,

Comment: well you are breaking out of the query you are building when you use `"` in the SQL as you have not escaped the quote  ... `CONCAT(chef_address.latitude,", ",chef_address.longitude)`  that `", "` is separating arguments, it is not part of your string ... so that array at the end is not the second argument  ... though that wouldn't explain the `null`

Comment: It seems work fine , Thanks a lot brother @lagbox

Comment: feel free to answer your own question if you would like :) and good luck, have fun